# How to identify users which are directly added to SharePoint site Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, powershell, permissions

How to identify users which are directly added to SharePoint site (not through any SharePoint Group ) without traversing whole site users using C# or powershell ?

Answer (score 0):

Without traversing manually to a website, you can get all users in Sharepoint on Premise by using following command:

```
Get-SPUser -Web "http://your_site_url"
```

you can check for other optional parameters in [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff607580.aspx)

Comment: We don't want to take all users and then check their permission, we want to check users in a particular permission level. Any leads on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate account and configure it in the application pool identity. You can get the original user name.Please checkout [Identify users and analyze document usage in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261954.aspx) and [how to get current user name (AD) in SharePoint programmatically?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e6857645-2459-4574-8b35-164c796b644a/how-to-get-current-user-name-ad-in-sharepoint-programmatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy) for detailed information.